# How to indicate that something happened at the same time as a prolonged event (a war) but not as part of that event

Tags: time, phrasing

The U.S.S Pueblo is a US ship that was captured by DPRK forces in 1968, at the same time that the Vietnam war was going on. I wrote a comment about the time of the event on a question on Skeptics.SE but I am not pleased with the wording.

> [T]he U.S.S Pueblo was not captured during the Korean war, but in 1968, at the same time as the Vietnam war was going on

How to express that this happened during the time of the Vietnam war, but was not related (at least directly) to the war.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you are asking how to write it better than what you wrote while keeping the nuances clear?

Comment: @Sid, yes, obviously that could be applied to other situations with this being just an example.

Comment: Maybe relevant; context for others: [Did the North Korean Navy sink the heavy cruiser U.S.S. Chicago by torpedo boat in 1950?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/39621/30880)

Comment: Doesn't *contemporaneously* do that job? Alternatively, just *in 1968, at the time of the Vietnam War*? Neither suggests the events are connected.

*During* the Vietnam War would be ambiguous.